# JQuery: Download function invokes XMLHttpRequest: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery, download

I am trying to download a file from website/s and it just throws an error about Access-Control. can anyone teach me how to make this code work? thanks in advance

```
  var jqxhr = $.get("http://www.somewebsite.com/matodb.csv", function() {
    alert("success");
  })
  .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
  .error(function() { alert("error"); })
  .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not make AJAX queries to other domains for security reasons ([Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)).

Comment: What you can do is make an ajax query to your side and get the file over PHP from your server.

Comment: Also you can execute javascript from other sides by adding a new <script> tag to the body.